# Bluetooth headphones: do they always have background noise?

Tags: laptop, audio, bluetooth

I bought cheap P47 bluetooth headphones. But they constantly have some background noise, which is unbearable. The sound differs on events like bluetooth pairing, and when my laptop's CPU usage changes.

So, I tried on a different computer (desktop), with a bluetooth dongle, disabling the other playback and recording devices, disabling the wifi in the room... The noise is still present.

As more, there is a high-pitched noise when sound is playing, typical of a low-quality sound encoding, presumably happening for the bluetooth transmission.

My question is: if I buy less cheap headphones (but still low budget...), will I encounter the same issue? Would there still be a background noise, though quieter? I'm very sound-sensitive, so I would really need something with no background sound at all.

Comment: I have a pair for 5.99 $, and there is no noise at all - the sound is crystal clear. I think yours are broken or otherwise inadequate.

Comment: What I want is crystal clear *silence* when there is no sound playing. Do you confirm your headphones don't make any noise in this situation?

Comment: Yep. Total silence.

Comment: For the record, I now use a higher-range headset (Sony MDR-ZX770BN), there is just no comparison, its sound is much, much better. Sounds just as well as a wired headset. Though it also has a small background noise when playing, which I solved by using [Equalizer APO](https://equalizerapo.com/) to add a preamplification (of +8 dB).

Answer (score 1):

Normally background noise or sound gaps comes into factor when the distance between the Bluetooth device and audio source increases beyond a certain distance. If you are facing this problem everytime, most probably there is some loose connection of wiring inside the Bluetooth device. If possible, get it replaced.